# Hardcoded urls : Refactor your code to get this URI from a customizable parameter

Tags: ios, plist, sonarqube-scan

Best way to save hardcode values?

**1) Plist**

**2) dictionary**

According to me, **plist** is not the safest option because it is easily recoverable through IPA.

But if I store URL endpoints in Dictionary then I am getting Sonar Qube warnings. **"Refactor your code to get this URI from a customizable parameter."**

Comment: Show the code, where you are adding that URL and getting this warning.

Comment: @rptwsthi                                                                                               internal init() {
        
        endPointDictionary =  [
                               "Login": "/Login",
                               "Logout": "/Logout"]
    }

Comment: Waring is coming for "/Login" and "/Logout". I tried with fetching values through plist then I didn't get any warnings but as it is not safe to use plist, So I tried with the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**Keychain** is the most secure place on the phone to store things. That doesn't mean it's unbreakable but less breakable as compare to others.

You can use a simple solution [SAMKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain), wrapper for the system keychain.